# fscanf() writing only some not all of the content from the input file

Tags: c, file, while-loop, fwrite, scanf

I am writing a code to convert a text file to a binary file. It doesnt return any errors and runs fine except for the fact that in this particular example it doesnt print the first name. My input file contains `john doe 1 4.0`. The expected output is `johndoe@▒`,but my output is `doe@▒`. I have tried using fseek to move the offset. I tried closing the files differently. I tried renaming my variable and changing the if statement.

I am not entirely sure, but I feel the error may be from the loop. If i swap firstName and lastName, the same thing occurs but reversed which means that my code omits whatever is read first using fwrite. What is wrong with my code that makes this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void textToBinary(char *inputFile, char *outputFile){

    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    char firstName[256], lastName[256];
    int sID; 
    float gpa;

    unsigned char firstNameLen = strlen(firstName);
    unsigned char lastNameLen = strlen(lastName);

    if(((ifp = fopen(inputFile, "r")) != NULL)&&((ofp = fopen(outputFile, "w")) != NULL)){
        while((fscanf(ifp, "%s %s %d %f\n", firstName, lastName, &sID, &gpa)) != EOF){
            fwrite(&firstNameLen, sizeof(firstNameLen), 1, ofp);
            fwrite(firstName, sizeof(char), firstNameLen, ofp);
            fwrite(&lastNameLen, sizeof(lastNameLen), 1, ofp);
            fwrite(lastName, sizeof(char), lastNameLen, ofp);
            fwrite(&sID, sizeof(int), 1, ofp);
            fwrite(&gpa, sizeof(float), 1, ofp);
        }
        fclose(ifp);
        fclose(ofp);
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open: %s\n", ifp);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You're computing `firstNameLen` and `lastNameLen` on garbage buffer values. These belong inside the loop.

Comment: Your `fscanf()` check should be `== 4` rather than `!= EOF`.  You might get numbers 0, 1, 2, or 3 as well as EOF, and all of them indicate problems.

Comment: `char firstName[256],  ...  unsigned char firstNameLen = strlen(firstName);` is UB

Comment: Stylistically, you'd do better to split the file opening over more lines. Use `if ((ifp = fopen(inputFile, "r")) == NULL) { …report error opening inputFIle… } else if ((ofp = fopen(outputFile, "w")) == NULL) { fclose(ifp); …report error opening outputFile… } else { …while loop and fcloses… }`.  That gives you more accurate error reporting and is more readable when appropriately spaced. Note that `printf("Couldn't open: %s\n", ifp);` is going to report the file name as `(null)` if you're lucky, or crash, if the input file couldn't be opened, and gibberish if the output file couldn't be opened.

Comment: Thanks @Gene that worked. I see what happened now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested re-write of code using above comments

```
//unsigned char firstNameLen = strlen(firstName);
//unsigned char lastNameLen = strlen(lastName);

if(((ifp = fopen(inputFile, "r")) != NULL)&&((ofp = fopen(outputFile, "w")) != NULL)){
    while((fscanf(ifp, "%255s %255s %d %f", firstName, lastName, &sID, &gpa)) == 4){
        unsigned char firstNameLen = strlen(firstName);
        unsigned char lastNameLen = strlen(lastName);
        fwrite(&firstNameLen, sizeof firstNameLen, 1, ofp);
        fwrite(firstName, sizeof *firstName, firstNameLen, ofp);
        fwrite(&lastNameLen, sizeof lastNameLen, 1, ofp);
        fwrite(lastName, sizeof *lastName, lastNameLen, ofp);
        fwrite(&sID, sizeof sID, 1, ofp);
        fwrite(&gpa, sizeof gpa, 1, ofp);
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
}else{
```

Comment: The variable type declaration should not be within the loop.

Comment: @JoeDF: what do you mean?  There's nothing wrong with variable declarations at the top of any statement block in any version of C.  In modern C (C99 or later), you can declare variables at any point in a statement block — they don't have to be at the top.

Comment: @JoeDF This is just a programming style. Nothing wrong with this.

Comment: C99+, I see. Understood.